# PHP 5.3 namespaces - functions not working as expected

Tags: php, namespaces

There are some functions not working properly with namespaces

```
<?php
namespace MyApp;
class Fruit {}
class Apple extends Fruit {}

$apple = new Apple();
$name = 'Apple';

var_dump (is_subclass_of($apple, 'Fruit'));
var_dump (is_a($apple, 'Apple'));
var_dump (new $name);
```

How can I make this compatible with both php 5.3 and php < 5.3 with no namespace support ?
is_subclass_of and is_a are not working like this !

Comment: What does not work as expected?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
<?php
namespace MyApp;
class Fruit {}
class Apple extends Fruit {}

$apple = new Apple();
$name = 'MyApp\Apple';

var_dump (is_subclass_of($apple, 'MyApp\Fruit'));
var_dump (is_a($apple, 'MyApp\Apple'));
var_dump (new $name);
```

You need to **fully qualify** your namespace name in functions that take a class name *as a string* instead of as a bareword.  Classes as barewords are resolved at runtime.  [Here's the PHP manual on namespace resolution](http://php.net/language.namespaces.rules), and [here's a page with examples using strings to fully qualify namespaces](http://php.net/language.namespaces.dynamic).

(Also note the single quotes to prevent backslash munching.)